# transform,transform-origin not working inside @keyframes

Tags: html, css

I want to tilt the image at the beginning and at the end. Image keyframes,transform and transform-origin doesn't seem to be working.

html:

```
 <div class="h_imag col-md-9">
          <img class="h_ig"src="top_right_image.gif" alt="">
        </div>
```

css:

```
.h_imag{
  min-height: 6px;
  float: right;
  animation: t_bike 10s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes t_bike {
0%    {top: 0px; left: 0px; -moz-transform: rotate(0 deg); -moz-transform-origin: -9px 15px;}
5%    {top: 0px; left: 1%; -moz-transform: rotate(-10 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 20px 0px;}
10%   {top: 0px; left: 4.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(-20 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 29px 0px;}
20%   {top: 0px; left: 9.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(-25 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
25%   {top: 0px; left: 13.8%; -moz-transform: rotate(-25 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
30%   {top: 0px; left: 18.4%; -moz-transform: rotate(-30 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
35%   {top: 0px; left: 23%; -moz-transform: rotate(-30 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
40%   {top: 0px; left: 27.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(-30 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
45%   {top: 0px; left: 32.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(-25 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
50%   {top: 0px; left: 36.8%; -moz-transform: rotate(-20 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
55%   {top: 0px; left: 41.4%; -moz-transform: rotate(0 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
60%   {top: 0px; left: 46%; -moz-transform: rotate(0 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
65%   {top: 0px; left: 50.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(0 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
70%   {top: 0px; left: 55.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(20 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 70px 0px;}
75%   {top: 0px; left: 59.8%; -moz-transform: rotate(25 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 70px 0px;}
80%   {top: 0px; left: 64.4%; -moz-transform: rotate(30 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 65px 0px;}
85%   {top: 0px; left: 69%; -moz-transform: rotate(30 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 65px 0px;}
90%   {top: 0px; left: 73.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(30 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 65px 0px;}
95%   {top: 0px; left: 78.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(10 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 75px 0px;}
100%   {top: 0px; left: 88%; -moz-transform: rotate(0 deg); -moz-transform-origin: -9px 15px;}
}
```

Comment: Is this only for Firefox? ... Also, Firefox dropped prefix 5 years ago, from version  16

Comment: Is there something missing in my answer for you to accept it?

Answer (score 1):

The major issue is the space you have in `0 deg`, should not be a space there, between the number and the `deg` characters.

If you plan to run this on all modern browsers, you need a none prefixed version too.

Also, since the top value is not changed, I moved it to the `h_imag` rule and added `position: relative;` for the `left` to work.

```css
.h_imag{
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 6px;
  float: right;
  animation: t_bike 10s infinite;
}

@keyframes t_bike {
0%    { left: 0px; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: -9px 15px; }
5%    { left: 1%; transform: rotate(-10deg); transform-origin: 20px 0px; }
10%   { left: 4.6%; transform: rotate(-20deg); transform-origin: 29px 0px; }
20%   { left: 9.2%; transform: rotate(-25deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
25%   { left: 13.8%; transform: rotate(-25deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
30%   { left: 18.4%; transform: rotate(-30deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
35%   { left: 23%; transform: rotate(-30deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
40%   { left: 27.6%; transform: rotate(-30deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
45%   { left: 32.2%; transform: rotate(-25deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
50%   { left: 36.8%; transform: rotate(-20deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
55%   { left: 41.4%; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
60%   { left: 46%; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; } 
65%   { left: 50.6%; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: 31px 0px; }
70%   { left: 55.2%; transform: rotate(20deg); transform-origin: 70px 0px; }
75%   { left: 59.8%; transform: rotate(25deg); transform-origin: 70px 0px; }
80%   { left: 64.4%; transform: rotate(30deg); transform-origin: 65px 0px; }
85%   { left: 69%; transform: rotate(30deg); transform-origin: 65px 0px; }
90%   { left: 73.6%; transform: rotate(30deg); transform-origin: 65px 0px; }
95%   { left: 78.2%; transform: rotate(10deg); transform-origin: 75px 0px; }
100%  { left: 88%; transform: rotate(0deg); transform-origin: -9px 15px; }
}
```

```html
<div class="h_imag col-md-9">
  <img class="h_ig" src="http://placehold.it/150" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why people don't use the **minimal** part of the request of the example. Posting an animation with 2 steps would be a **minimal** example much easier to follow and fix ....

Comment: @vals True ... :) ... and I guess its us, who have the experience to break down things in pieces when looking for error, who see the easiness in doing it that way

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is not working inside that, then that means it is not running at all.

It think the problem is at the normal css for h_imag.

Change this:

```
animation: t_bike 10s infinite;
```

To this:

```
-moz-animation: t_bike 10s infinite;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces between rotation number and rotation unit example `90 deg`. remove these spcaes. Also add prefixes to your transform property and keyframes for cross browser compat.

```css
.h_imag{
  min-height: 6px;
  float: right;
  animation: t_bike 10s infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes t_bike {
0%    {top: 0px; left: 0px; -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: -9px 15px;}
5%    {top: 0px; left: 1%; -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg); -moz-transform-origin: 20px 0px;}
10%   {top: 0px; left: 4.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg); -moz-transform-origin: 29px 0px;}
20%   {top: 0px; left: 9.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(-25deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
25%   {top: 0px; left: 13.8%; -moz-transform: rotate(-25deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
30%   {top: 0px; left: 18.4%; -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
35%   {top: 0px; left: 23%; -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
40%   {top: 0px; left: 27.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
45%   {top: 0px; left: 32.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(-25deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
50%   {top: 0px; left: 36.8%; -moz-transform: rotate(-20deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
55%   {top: 0px; left: 41.4%; -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
60%   {top: 0px; left: 46%; -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
65%   {top: 0px; left: 50.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: 31px 0px;}
70%   {top: 0px; left: 55.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(20 deg); -moz-transform-origin: 70px 0px;}
75%   {top: 0px; left: 59.8%; -moz-transform: rotate(25deg); -moz-transform-origin: 70px 0px;}
80%   {top: 0px; left: 64.4%; -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); -moz-transform-origin: 65px 0px;}
85%   {top: 0px; left: 69%; -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); -moz-transform-origin: 65px 0px;}
90%   {top: 0px; left: 73.6%; -moz-transform: rotate(30deg); -moz-transform-origin: 65px 0px;}
95%   {top: 0px; left: 78.2%; -moz-transform: rotate(10deg); -moz-transform-origin: 75px 0px;}
100%   {top: 0px; left: 88%; -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); -moz-transform-origin: -9px 15px;}
}
```

```html
 <div class="h_imag col-md-9">
          <img class="h_ig"src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRjKEpedzfPj_kXxRz3OIoNsVzWrLJWsr6xzN-gjYYUxfvbCsOXBg" alt="">
        </div>
```